# jQuery infinite scroll missing css background load amount pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using the lastest version of infinite-scroll (by paulirish). Everything is work fine, but there is very strange issue, actually I don't know this is an issue or not.

Well, let's imagine:
You've a forum, and you're using infinite scroll in a thread with about 20 pages. You can load smoothly about 8 pages. But after that, it's impossible to load full css (the background image in css) for the 9th page.

You can see a screenshot here : http://photo.luyencong.net/images/infinitesc.png 
Do you meet this issue or any issue like this before? Please give me some advices, thanks a lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's separate your big background into three smaller parts.

HTML

```
<div id="start_part">...</div>
<div id="content_part">
    <div class="wrapper">...</div>
</div>
<div id="end_part">...</div>
```

CSS

```
#start_part { 
    background: url("top-part.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#content_part {
    background: url("center-part.jpg") no-repeat fixed center top transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#content_part .wrapper1 {
    background: url("top-part.jpg") 1px 0 no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
}
#content_part .wrapper2 {
    background: url("bottom-part.jpg") 1px 0 no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
}
#end_part {
    background: url("top-part.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Hope it may helps.

Comment: This one really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are scrolling the background image as your scroll down. Fix the background image:

```
background-image:url('yourbackground.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment